# LaTeX3: \fp_pow:Nn giving wrong results

Tags: latex3

I want to draw the square-root from a rational number using the `l3fp` package. As the package does not provide an sqrt function, I played with `\fp_pow:Nn`. Unfortunately, I could only get the correct result for $\sqrt{4}$:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_set:Nn\a_fp{0.04}
\fp_pow:Nn\a_fp{0.5}
\fp_use:N\a_fp\par    %wrong

\fp_set:Nn\a_fp{4.0}
\fp_pow:Nn\a_fp{0.5}
\fp_use:N\a_fp\par    %ok

\fp_set:Nn\a_fp{9.0}
\fp_pow:Nn\a_fp{0.5}
\fp_use:N\a_fp\par    %wrong

\fp_set:Nn\a_fp{16.0}
\fp_pow:Nn\a_fp{0.5}
\fp_use:N\a_fp\par    %wrong

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is an open bug report on this (https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/issues/10). Currently, fixing it has not been high-priority as (1) we are not using powers for typesetting and (2) Bruno Le Floch is working on an overall reimplementation of the module which will be more robust/efficient and also expandable. I will see if I can fix it: the code for this part is not very easy to follow.

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks for the pointer. I searched the bugs on latex-project but didn't find anything related.

Comment: Bugs for LaTeX3 are currently collected on GitHub. The main Project bugs database is better suited to a mature system than the transitory stuff we get for `expl3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joseph said, the code is quite intricate. The bug should be fixed in the SVN (and probably in the next week or so on CTAN with the next update of expl3).

If you cannot wait, you can also redefine the offending function `\fp_pow_aux_iv:`. Only the end changes, but the function is massive.

```
\cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn \fp_pow_aux_iv:
  {
    \group_begin:
      \l_fp_input_a_integer_int  \l_fp_input_b_integer_int
      \l_fp_input_a_decimal_int  \l_fp_input_b_decimal_int
      \l_fp_input_a_exponent_int \l_fp_input_b_exponent_int
      \fp_ln_internal:
      \cs_set_protected_nopar:Npx \fp_tmp:w
        {
          \group_end:
          \exp_not:N \l_fp_input_b_sign_int
            \int_use:N \l_fp_output_sign_int \scan_stop:
          \exp_not:N \l_fp_input_b_integer_int
            \int_use:N \l_fp_output_integer_int \scan_stop:
          \exp_not:N \l_fp_input_b_decimal_int
            \int_use:N \l_fp_output_decimal_int \scan_stop:
          \exp_not:N \l_fp_input_b_extended_int
            \int_use:N \l_fp_output_extended_int \scan_stop:
          \exp_not:N \l_fp_input_b_exponent_int
            \int_use:N \l_fp_output_exponent_int \scan_stop:
        }
    \fp_tmp:w
    \l_fp_input_a_extended_int  \c_zero
    \fp_mul:NNNNNNNNN
      \l_fp_input_a_integer_int \l_fp_input_a_decimal_int
        \l_fp_input_a_extended_int
      \l_fp_input_b_integer_int \l_fp_input_b_decimal_int
        \l_fp_input_b_extended_int
      \l_fp_output_integer_int \l_fp_output_decimal_int
        \l_fp_output_extended_int
    \l_fp_output_exponent_int
      \int_eval:w
        \l_fp_input_a_exponent_int + \l_fp_input_b_exponent_int
      \scan_stop:
    \fp_extended_normalise_output:
    \tex_multiply:D \l_fp_input_a_sign_int \l_fp_input_b_sign_int
    \l_fp_input_a_integer_int  \l_fp_output_integer_int
    \l_fp_input_a_decimal_int  \l_fp_output_decimal_int
    \l_fp_input_a_extended_int \l_fp_output_extended_int
    \l_fp_input_a_exponent_int \l_fp_output_exponent_int
    \l_fp_output_integer_int  \c_zero
    \l_fp_output_decimal_int  \c_zero
    \l_fp_output_extended_int \c_zero
    \l_fp_output_exponent_int \c_zero
    \cs_set_eq:NN \fp_exp_const:Nx \use_none:nn
    \fp_exp_internal:
  }
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Bruno. I updated `l3kernel` this morning and everything works as expected now.

Comment: @Alexander: thank Joseph Wright for most of the fp module. I'm working hard on a complete rewrite with 16 significant digits, proper handling of exceptions, and "exact" rounding (as per IEEE 854), and realising that it is _hard_ to do better than the current.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough

```
\fp_set:Nn\a_fp{0.04}
\fp_ln:Nn\a_fp{\a_fp}
\fp_div:Nn\a_fp{2}
\fp_exp:Nn\a_fp{\a_fp}
\fp_use:N\a_fp\par
```

prints 0.2000000010, but using `4` as argument prints 1.999999999.

After `\fp_set:Nn\a_fp{0.04}` and `\fp_pow:Nn\a_fp{0.5}`, `\fp_show:N\a_fp` shows `+2.624477407e0`. When used with 4 it shows `+2.000000000e0`. When used with `400` it says "Number too big"!

Note: my version of l3fp.sty is `l3fp.dtx 2201 2011-03-19 17:16:13Z`